# Dynamically modify yaml and preserve all formatting and comments - python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a `config.yml` file like this:

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 1 blah 
# COMMENT 2 blah blah
# COMMENT 3 blah blah blah

NAME: Fruits

# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 4 blah 
# COMMENT 5 blah blah
# COMMENT 6 blah blah blah

fruit_list:
  - "apple-01:9100"
```

I want to dynamically modify the `fruit_list`. I want to append user inputted data from a flask web form. Below is the code I tried, I am only able to modify and append one string with this code.

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
conf_file = pathlib.Path('configs/config.yml')
conf_key = yaml.load(conf_file)
conf_key['Fruits'] = form.bsa.data
conf_key['fruit_list'] = form.fqdn.data + ':9100'
yaml.dump(conf_key, conf_file)
```

The above code lets me only modify / append one string to `fruit_list`. Also, it does not preserve the formatting. Comments are preserved, but spacing is a mess and keeps increasing spaces. See output below:

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE

# COMMENT 1 blah 

# COMMENT 2 blah blah

# COMMENT 3 blah blah blah

NAME: Fruits

# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 4 blah 
# COMMENT 5 blah blah
# COMMENT 6 blah blah blah

fruit_list: apple-01:9100
```

The desired output will be as follows:

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 1 blah 
# COMMENT 2 blah blah
# COMMENT 3 blah blah blah

NAME: Fruits

# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 4 blah 
# COMMENT 5 blah blah
# COMMENT 6 blah blah blah

fruit_list:
  - "apple-01:9100"
  - "orange-01:9100"
  - "pear-01:9100"
  - "grape-01:9100"
```

I would also like the appending in `fruit_list` to be dynamic based on how many `fruits` the user has inputted.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your YAML input (apart from using
`.yml` extension, since 2006 the [recommended extension for YAML files has been
`.yaml`](https://yaml.org/faq) ). I suspect your input has some extra cariage returns or some other stuff,
so make sure you check that by doing `print(repr(conf_key))` and possible

```
conf_key = conf_key.replace('\r', '\n')
```

or similar to clean things up. As shown below, I cannot reproduce geting the extra newlines

As for appending to the YAML sequence, if you want that you have to append to the
corresponding list in Python. And not assign a new, non-list, value to the key of
the parent dict:

```
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

conf_file = pathlib.Path('config.yaml')


conf_file.write_text("""\
# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 1 blah 
# COMMENT 2 blah blah
# COMMENT 3 blah blah blah

NAME: Fruits

# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 4 blah 
# COMMENT 5 blah blah
# COMMENT 6 blah blah blah

fruit_list:
  - "apple-01:9100"
""")

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
conf_key = yaml.load(conf_file)
conf_key['Fruits'] = 'some_data'
conf_key['fruit_list'].append('orange-01:9100')
conf_key['fruit_list'].extend(['pear-01:9100', 'grape-01:9100'])
yaml.dump(conf_key, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 1 blah 
# COMMENT 2 blah blah
# COMMENT 3 blah blah blah

NAME: Fruits

# CONFIGURATION FILE
# COMMENT 4 blah 
# COMMENT 5 blah blah
# COMMENT 6 blah blah blah

fruit_list:
  - apple-01:9100
  - orange-01:9100
  - pear-01:9100
  - grape-01:9100
Fruits: some_data
```

With your code you should also expect an extra key `Fruits` in the root level mapping.

In general it is better to
write to a different file, or stdout, while testing: no need to restore your original input.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon. I'll try and get back.